# C# Excel formula indicator

Tags: c#, excel

I want to convert the data of Excel file in the DataTable for edit. But cells with formulas should not be editable. How do I find that the cell contains a formula, if I get the calculated value in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.HasFormula` property of `Range`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.hasformula.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Range.SpecialCellsmethod enables to get cells with constant values or formulas.